# how to deploy java web project using ant on gcloud vm instance

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud, gcloud-java

I have searched out for gcloud doc for java web project deployment but I got only maven project doc in result. Project already created in google cloud console and google sdk also installed.

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help)it will be useful to lift your content quality up

Answer (score 0):

One method is to simply connecting to the google cloud machine with sshexec & scp tasks in ant, and deposit a tarball and extract, an example might be..:

```
<target name="deploy-staging" description="Deploy to staging">
        <input message="Staging Passphrase:" addproperty="my.password">
            <handler classname="org.apache.tools.ant.input.SecureInputHandler" />
        </input>
        <!-- Create the new release folder on host-->
        <sshexec trust="true"
                 host="hosthere"
                 username="username"
                 keyfile="${user.home}/.ssh/keyfile"
                 passphrase="${my.password}"
                 command="mkdir /var/www/releases/${git.revision}" />

        <!-- Push the application tarball to the server-->
        <scp trust="true"
             file="${basedir}/build/${git.revision}.tar.gz"
             todir="username@${hosthere}:/var/www/releases/${git.revision}"
             keyfile="${user.home}/.ssh/keyfile"
             passphrase="${my.password}"/>

        <!-- Extract the tarball on the server-->
        <sshexec trust="true"
                 host="${hosthere}"
                 username="username"
                 keyfile="${user.home}/.ssh/keyfile"
                 passphrase="${my.password}"
                 command="cd /var/www/releases/${git.revision}; tar -xvzf ${git.revision}.tar.gz" />
        <sshexec trust="true"
                 host="${hosthere}"
                 username="username"
                 keyfile="${user.home}/.ssh/keyfile"
                 passphrase="${my.password}"
                 command="rm -rf /var/www/current" />

        <sshexec trust="true"
                 host="${hosthere}"
                 username="username"
                 keyfile="${user.home}/.ssh/keyfile"
                 passphrase="${my.password}"
                 command="ln -s /var/www/releases/${git.revision} -T /var/www/current" />
     </target>
```

**The above isn't tested.. ended up using this whilst searching for a better way to handle gcloud instanced groups.**